# response.GetResponseStream(); returns // seen-all-campaigns

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
  request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
  request.Timeout = 20000;

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  Encoding encodings = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
  string strLastRedirect = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, encodings);
  string streamreader = reader.ReadToEnd();
  response.Dispose();
  request.Abort();
```

My code is this but streamReader returns "//seen all compaing" everytime

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your question is, but I have spotted a problem with your code. The following line is using `dataStream3` which isn't declared in the above code block.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream3, encodings);
```

To make it correspond with this code block, it should be referencing the `dataStream` variable.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, encodings);
```

Comment: request.GetResponse()   not giving any response & streamReader returns "//seen-all-campaign"